# Need help intercepting android application network traffic

Tags: android

On my OWN rooted phone, I have had xposed installed, justtrustme unpinning application, and tcpdump in an attempt to capture the traffic of specific applications that are on the phone.

The specific application I am trying to decipher is using some advanced certificate pinning. I don't care about anything other than what are the requests that it sends to the API servers.

I have also tried frida.re but there are just so many function calls to figure out which one is the one I am interested in.

Any advice?